# using = sign in function parameter in python

Tags: python, function, opencv, parameters

What is the use of = sign in following function in python

```
res=cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask)
```

why we need `mask= mask` in it?
**Thanks you**

Comment: They  Are called default arguments

Comment: To put it generally, that's a _keyword argument_. But without more context, that's probably all we can really tell you.

Comment: the first mask is a named-parameter, the second should be a variable defined above in your code. it's a way to pass [some parameters](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments)

Comment: @Rahul it is not definition of function but i am calling it

Comment: mask on the right is a variable assigning a value to the mask (on the left) parameter.

Comment: It is useless to write program which you don't understand. read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you can define the optional parameters like:

```
def func(par, mask=1):
    pass
```

and when you call the `func` function you can optionally specify the parameter `mask`.

```
func(2,mask=2)
```

lets assume you have mask variable that has been assigned value before you call `func` function

you can call like this

```
func(2,mask=mask)
```

back to your question the reason we have to specify `mask=mask` and not just call the function like `func(2,3)` is we may have more than one optional parameters like

```
 def func2(par1,opt1=1,opt2=3):
        pass
```

Here when you call `func2` and want to pass value for `par1 and opt2` You have to call like this `func2(2,opt2=5)`

Answer (score 0):

The first `mask` is a variable defined in the function definition. The second `mask` is an argument which you are passing to the function. The `=` is there because the function definition must require it to be there as it's a default argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it for explicit defenition of function's parameter.

For example you have next function defenition:

`def add_action(action,time=datetime.now, mode=0):`

In this function time and mode have predefined values(because this values can be most frequent uses for this function), and in cases where you have to change this predefined values you can only send them in needed direction:

```
add_action(action, datetime(2017, 08, 19), 1)
```

or send via their names, if you want to redefine only 1 parameter:

```
add_action(action, mode=2)
```

So, time would have the predefined value.

Also you can write function like:

```
def foo(par1, **kwargs)
```

Here par1 is obligatory parameter, and other parameters that you will send to function via names, will be in **kwargs that actualy is key word dictionary.

So if you invoke next function:

```
foo(value1, mode=1, date=now(), message='Hello')
```

In function body **kwargs will have next value:

`{
  mode:1,
  date:datetime(2017, 08, 19, 14, 24, 56, 22393),//result of function now()
  message:'Hello'
}`